# AWS EC2 terminate command giving "Service ec2 not available" error from Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running this command `aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(ec2metadata --instance-id)` in Ubuntu via Ansible as root.

And I'm getting this error:

`"stderr": "Service ec2 not available in region aws-east-1"`

**What does this mean?  Does it mean that I can't terminate instances in the region aws-east-1?**

But, when I run that command manually in the cmd, it terminates well! How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the credentials/config file on your ubuntu instance, do you have the region set to aws-east-1 instead of us-east-1? aws-east-1 is not a valid region.

Comment: Damn!  Silly error in my config setting bash file!  Thanks for the answer :)